# Was there a noticeable drop in the number of requests after releasing the live update feature?

Tags: discussion, live-refresh

Over the last few weeks I noticed a cool feature on SO where reputation and other attributes appear to be pushed to the browser, making it so I don't have to manually refresh to see reputation changes. I suspect this feature was driven to help reduce the number of requests from people simply refreshing the browser, if this is the case, have you guys noticed any significant decreases in the number of requests?

Comment: My `F5` key feels like I'm ignoring him :(

Comment: @Lix: I thought your <kbd>F5</kbd> was broken??

Comment: @man - where did you get *that* from?

Comment: @Lix: I thought that applied to _any_ active SO user that's been a member for at least half a year. `{{citation needed}}` though :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I suspect this feature was driven to help reduce the number of requests from people simply refreshing the browser

Not at all, the feature was driven by the underlying goal of making our sites more awesome. It feels more awesome when you don't have to wait and stuff just happens without needing to hit the "refresh" button.

The median visitor will only visit a single page in a day, average will visit less than 2.

> have you guys noticed any significant decreases in the number of requests?

Well, we did not expect a noticeable decrease in the number of page views. Firstly it makes no sense since most users only visit a page. Secondly, when we improve our site and increase the awesome we usually notice an increase in traffic (which may be slightly counter intuitive here, but I believe still holds)

More concretely page views on Stack Overflow have been on the rise, we did notice a rather large increase around March 20 which may be due to data center changes (increased bandwidth), perf improvements or the moon.

Comment: `"It's not a bug... Its an [awesomeness-request]"`

Comment: Needs more waffles.

Comment: It's always the moon...

Comment: @waffles http://i.stack.imgur.com/1BUAu.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the response. I asked out of personal interaction with SO where my actual refreshes diminished greatly with the live-refresh feature. I agree with Lix, my f5 key finally gets a well earned vacation.

Comment: [You were creepy today](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/946685#946685).